# get selected node jtree java

Tags: java

Here is my `JTree`

```
javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode1 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode(".Net Framework");
javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode2 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("Install");
javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode3 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("V1");
treeNode2.add(treeNode3);

treeNode3 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("V2");
treeNode2.add(treeNode3);

treeNode3 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("V3");
treeNode2.add(treeNode3);

treeNode3 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("V4");
treeNode2.add(treeNode3);
treeNode1.add(treeNode2);

treeNode2 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("Repair");
treeNode3 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("V1");
treeNode2.add(treeNode3);

treeNode3 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("V2");
treeNode2.add(treeNode3);

treeNode3 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("V3");
treeNode2.add(treeNode3);

treeNode3 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("V4");
treeNode2.add(treeNode3);
treeNode1.add(treeNode2);

treeNode2 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("Removal");
treeNode3 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("Remove All");
treeNode2.add(treeNode3);
treeNode1.add(treeNode2);

jTree2.setModel(new javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel(treeNode1));
jScrollPane5.setViewportView(jTree2);
```

here is the code that almost works

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) jTree2.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

if (node == null) {
      //Nothing is selected.     
    return;
}

if (node.isLeaf()) {
    System.out.println(node);
}
```

I want to be able to make if statements that say if leaf node V1 in the Install Node, then do this. Just not sure what to do with `if(node.equals(thisleaf)))`, what the `thisleaf` object should be equal to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a field

```
private DefaultMutableTreeNode v1Node;
```

Change the third line to

```
this.v1Node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("V1");
```

and use

```
if (node.equals(this.v1Node))
```

Side note: you should import `javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode` and make your code more readable by simply using `DefaultMutableTreeNode` instead of the fully qualified name. You should also choose meaningful variable names instead of treeNode1, jTree2, etc. Such bad names make the code very hard to understand.